# Hive derby issue

Tags: hadoop, hive

I installed hive-0.12.0 recenlty, But when I run queries in hive shell it shows the below error:

*FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient*

This is contained in my hive-default.xml.template:

```
javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL
jdbc:derby:;databaseName=/home/hduser/hive-0.12.0/metastore/metastore_db;create=true
JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore
```

Could any one help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems problem with your metastore. Since you are using the default hive metastore embedded derby. Lock file would be there in case of abnormal exit. if you remove that lock file this issue should get  solve

rm   metastore_db/*.lck